# Can't convert dates in WaveletComp

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet, wavelet-transform

First, here's the dput of my data:

```
WaveletSite1Oxygen2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(741830400, 746668800, 749088000, 
751507200, 753926400, 756345600, 759369600, 761788800, 764208000, 
766627200, 770256000, 773366400, 778118400, 780537600, 782956800, 
785462400, 790819200, 793238400, 795657600, 798681600, 801100800, 
803865600, 807148800, 809568000, 812073600, 814406400, 817257600, 
822873600, 825897600, 828316800, 831340800, 838598400, 841017600, 
843436800, 846460800, 848880000, 851904000, 854323200, 855619200, 
859334400, 864864000, 868320000, 872208000, 875491200, 877910400, 
879379200, 883353600, 885772800, 888192000, 890611200, 893289600, 
900028800, 904521600, 906940800, 909360000, 911779200, 912988800, 
916617600, 919382400, 921456000, 925084800, 928108800, 930268800, 
933292800, 935712000, 938131200, 941155200, 942364800, 949017600, 
951436800, 953856000, 955065600, 964137600, 966556800, 970185600, 
972604800, 973814400, 977443200, 979862400, 982800000, 985910400, 
987984000, 990748800, 993168000, 994377600, 998092800, 1000512000, 
1005350400, 1007769600, 1013817600, 1016236800, 1019260800, 1020297600, 
1025308800, 1027728000, 1030147200, 1032566400, 1034985600, 1038614400, 
1039824000, 1043452800, 1045872000, 1048291200, 1050624000, 1053129600, 
1056758400, 1059177600, 1060387200, 1064016000, 1066435200, 1070064000, 
1071273600, 1074902400, 1077321600, 1079740800, 1083024000, 1084579200, 
1087948800, 1091232000, 1093651200, 1096070400, 1098489600, 1100908800, 
1103328000, 1106352000, 1108771200, 1111190400, 1114819200, 1116028800, 
1117843200, 1122076800, 1124496000, 1128038400, 1130544000, 1133222400, 
1135123200, 1138665600, 1140566400, 1143244800, 1145577600, 1147996800, 
1151107200, 1154131200, 1156550400, 1158883200, 1161388800, 1163808000, 
1166140800, 1169164800, 1171670400, 1175299200, 1177632000, 1180051200, 
1183161600, 1185580800, 1.188e+09, 1190419200, 1191628800, 1196294400, 
1197676800, 1200614400, 1203120000, 1206748800, 1209168000, 1210377600, 
1214006400, 1215129600, 1220054400, 1222473600, 1224892800, 1227312000, 
1229731200, 1232755200, 1235174400, 1236384000, 1240012800, 1242432000, 
1248480000, 1250553600, 1253318400, 1256947200, 1259280000, 1260576000, 
1262995200, 1266710400, 1269043200, 1272326400, 1275091200, 1280534400, 
1282953600, 1285372800, 1287792000, 1290211200, 1292544000, 1295568000, 
1298073600, 1299283200, 1304035200, 1306454400, 1307664000, 1311638400, 
1314057600, 1316476800, 1318809600, 1322611200, 1323820800, 1326499200, 
1330473600, 1332892800, 1335312000, 1337731200, 1340064000, 1342569600, 
1346112000, 1348531200, 1350950400, 1353542400, 1355788800, 1358985600, 
1360022400, 1363392000, 1366070400, 1369699200, 1374710400, 1377216000, 
1379030400, 1382054400, 1384473600, 1386892800, 1391126400, 1395360000, 
1397779200, 1401235200, 1406246400, 1408579200, 1410998400, 1414713600, 
1417046400, 1418428800, 1421712000, 1424044800, 1426723200, 1430352000, 
1432944000, 1435276800, 1437523200, 1440028800, 1443398400, 1444867200, 
1447372800, 1449619200, 1451952000, 1454976000, 1459382400, 1461715200, 
1463011200, 1466726400, 1472601600, 1479168000, 1481155200, 1484179200, 
1487721600, 1488931200, 1491350400, 1493769600, 1498780800, 1501027200, 
1503446400, 1508544000, 1513296000, 1516060800, 1519171200, 1520812800, 
1522886400, 1525219200), tclass = "Date", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), AverageOxygen = c(4.11230769230769, 3.80128205128205, 
3.64576923076923, 5.76538461538462, 5.23153846153846, 5.14807692307692, 
4.26590909090909, 3.71666666666667, 4.35884615384615, 3.25769230769231, 
4.85288461538462, 5.61923076923077, 4.35576923076923, 5.72884615384615, 
7.22692307692308, 2, 4.21923076923077, 4.67211538461538, 5.125, 
4.74230769230769, 4.28846153846154, 5.10384615384615, 6.06346153846154, 
3.24230769230769, 6.07884615384615, 5.89615384615385, 4.54807692307692, 
5.21442307692308, 5.48461538461538, 6.70769230769231, 5.36538461538461, 
5.17483974358974, 5.95, 5.55384615384615, 5.67153846153846, 5.53769230769231, 
5.78307692307692, 6.57307692307692, 6.49192307692308, 6.36153846153846, 
6.71992307692308, 6.51936923076923, 6.41, 7.14782608695652, 6.11307692307692, 
6.20961538461538, 6.85277777777778, 6.82277777777778, 6.82846153846154, 
6.35384615384615, 5.15769230769231, 6.64, 6.39384615384615, 6.88179487179487, 
6.44153846153846, 6.82192307692308, 7.45923076923077, 7.03730769230769, 
7.01214285714286, 6.99326923076923, 6.83269230769231, 7.20188461538462, 
5.94901602564103, 4.195, 5.11826923076923, 6.94230769230769, 
6, 9.515, 7.95634615384615, 7.645, 6.72096153846154, 6.09538461538462, 
6.65636639676113, 6.80596153846154, 6.19564102564103, 7.03442307692308, 
6.52769230769231, 7.48740384615385, 7.22692307692308, 7.05307692307692, 
6.06953846153846, 5.41384615384615, 7.17278846153846, 7.47373076923077, 
7.1822792022792, 6.80788461538462, 7.24076923076923, 7.54961538461538, 
5.55653846153846, 8.41923076923077, 6.75423076923077, 7.13653846153846, 
7.00192307692308, 7.09538461538462, 7.29730769230769, 7.42903846153846, 
5.87115384615385, 5.94153846153846, 6.42153846153846, 6.74269230769231, 
5.88730769230769, 6.41692307692308, 6.82653846153846, 6.34096153846154, 
6.19807692307692, 6.79384615384615, 6.56230769230769, 4.40576923076923, 
6.54115384615385, 6.02884615384615, 5.75666666666667, 5.01076923076923, 
5.55115384615385, 7.14961538461538, 5.77942307692308, 6.22141025641026, 
6.66192307692308, 6.06788461538462, 5.91153846153846, 5.37692307692308, 
5.61346153846154, 5.40192307692308, 6.41019230769231, 5.07961538461538, 
5.09391025641026, 2.42012820512821, 1.75173076923077, 4.14705128205128, 
4.44538461538462, 4.42269230769231, 2.94395833333333, 4.88153846153846, 
5.15941483516484, 5.35596153846154, 5.26211538461538, 4.02961538461538, 
2.60641254578755, 1.14916666666667, 4.67846153846154, 4.47653846153846, 
3.97942307692308, 2.27812937062937, 1.98057692307692, 1.92730769230769, 
4.65846153846154, 4.47173076923077, 5.02192307692308, 5.22423076923077, 
4.07393162393162, 3.72826923076923, 3.01666666666667, 3.96634615384615, 
4.85800480769231, 6.00442307692308, 6.44865384615385, 6.33692307692308, 
5.90365384615385, 6.57846153846154, 5.57615384615385, 6.25384615384615, 
5.31096153846154, 5.13022435897436, 4.98307692307692, 5.95038461538462, 
4.89730769230769, 5.2225, 5.805, 5.91642081447964, 5.97115384615385, 
5.25051282051282, 6.03519230769231, 5.66884615384615, 5.87538461538461, 
6.06269230769231, 5.81807692307692, 5.94423076923077, 6.19153846153846, 
5.54194762684124, 5.31923076923077, 6.35384615384615, 6.92051282051282, 
7.19038461538462, 3.90384615384615, 7.64230769230769, 6.03589743589744, 
6.51538461538462, 6.92820512820513, 6.81153846153846, 6.55897435897436, 
6.36192307692308, 7.22307692307692, 6.10961538461538, 5.93653846153846, 
6.85, 6.66538461538462, 5.12307692307692, 6.06153846153846, 6.42179487179487, 
6.32051282051282, 5.85384615384615, 6.27307692307692, 7.02692307692308, 
7.025, 6.02307692307692, 6.33173076923077, 6.47692307692308, 
5.37884615384615, 2.38644688644689, 5.91538461538462, 5.31730769230769, 
4.83461538461538, 1.25149572649573, 1.75757936507937, 2.47307692307692, 
4.47115384615385, 4.81548717948718, 4.43502747252747, 5.33873626373626, 
5.19423076923077, 5.90384615384615, 4.84038461538462, 5.45769230769231, 
5.89487179487179, 1.63846153846154, 5.35576923076923, 7.03846153846154, 
5.59230769230769, 5.84230769230769, 6.024, 3.81153846153846, 
3.83846153846154, 5.7, 6.10769230769231, 5.32307692307692, 5.59423076923077, 
6.86923076923077, 6.69028286528286, 6.57792022792023, 5.83846153846154, 
3.90384615384615, 0.761111111111111, 3.08098290598291, 4.68205128205128, 
4.51730769230769, 5.82692307692308, 1.52692307692308, 2.55769230769231, 
2.41410256410256, 2.32142697881828, 2.16333333333333, 0.778571428571429, 
1.40384615384615, 2.93846153846154, 2.74326923076923, 5.20769230769231, 
3.86269230769231, 4.02076923076923, 2.32545833333333, 4.35038461538462, 
5.60307692307692, 3.755, 5.00961538461539, 4.36307692307692, 
3.245, 4.38769230769231, 3.26269230769231, 4.00121082621083, 
4.79653846153846, 4.46518518518519, 5.34461538461538, 0.555384615384615, 
2.92332867132867, 4.17307692307692, 4.87461538461538, 5.50230769230769
)), row.names = c(NA, -275L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm using a package called WaveletComp to create wavelet graphs of my time series. The problem is, after I convert my time series into the wavelet analyzing function below and graph it, I can't change the time scale.

```
try <- analyze.wavelet(transform(WaveletSite1Oxygen2, date=Date), my.series="AverageOxygen", loess.span = 1/25,
 dt = 1, dj = 1/250,
 lowerPeriod = 2,
 upperPeriod = 16,
 make.pval = TRUE, method = "white.noise", params = NULL,
 n.sim = 10,
 verbose = TRUE)
#code for analyzing function
wt.image(try, periodlab = "periods",
+          legend.params = list(lab = "wavelet power levels"),
+          label.time.axis = TRUE,
+          show.date = TRUE, date.format = "%Y-%m")
# code for graph
```

The documentation says that once the date column is in POSIXct format, you should be able to manipulate it with the date.format command. However, the graph only shows the years in five-year intervals. So, it must be reading the column to some extent, but not fully?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it seems to be a little bug, because I have not been able to find a solution.

But you can do this:

First:

1- Use `trace(wt.image, edit=T)`

2-go to line 395 of code and paste there:

```
    plot(my.date, seq(min(axis.2), 
      max(axis.2), length.out = WT$nc), xlim = my.xlim, 
      ylim = my.ylim, type = "n", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", 
      yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", lwd = lwd.axis, 
      tck = timetck, tcl = timetcl, mgp = par()$mgp - 
        c(0, 0.5, 0), font = par()$font.axis, cex.axis = par()$cex.axis, 
      axes = F)

      axis(2, labels = F)
      axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(as.Date("1995-01-01", 
                                       format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = as.Date("1970-01-01", 
                                                                             format = "%Y-%m-%d")), as.Date("2015-01-01", 
                                                                                                            , format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = as.Date("1970-01-01", 
                                                                                                                                                    format = "%Y-%m-%d")), length.out = WT$nc/5), 
                   format = "%Y-%m", cex.axis = 1, las = 2)
```

Then, press save.

If you execute

```
wt.image(try, periodlab = "periods", n.levels = 200,
         legend.params = list(lab = "wavelet power levels"),
         label.time.axis = T,timelab = "",
         show.date = T, date.format = "%Y-%m" )
```

You will get this:

[image]

You can change the font size of the labels by modifying `cex.axis`, the number of labels shown be modifying `length.out` and `las` 1 for vertical and 2 for horizontal labels

For full x-label ticks:

```
plot(my.date, seq(min(axis.2), 
          max(axis.2), length.out = WT$nc), xlim = my.xlim, 
          ylim = my.ylim, type = "n", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", 
          yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", lwd = lwd.axis, 
          tck = timetck, tcl = timetcl, mgp = par()$mgp - 
            c(0, 0.5, 0), font = par()$font.axis, cex.axis = par()$cex.axis, 
          axes = F)

          axis(2, labels = F)
          axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(as.Date("1993-07-01", 
                                           format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = as.Date("1970-01-01", 
                                                                                 format = "%Y-%m-%d")), as.Date("2018-05-01", 
                                                                                                                , format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = as.Date("1970-01-01", 
                                                                                                                                                        format = "%Y-%m-%d")), length.out = WT$nc/5), 
                       format = "%Y-%m", cex.axis = 1, las = 2)
```

[image]

I am sorry I cannot give you a cleaner solution!
Best

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! I'll have to report the bug or email the people to see if it truly is a bug. 
Is there anyway to stretch out the label distance so that it fills out the entire x-axis?

Comment: Sure! Change "1995-01-01" for "1993-07-01" and "2015-01-01" for "2018-05-01". If it is a bug, I will be happy to help with! Best! Find attached  the result in my edited answer.

Comment: That's very kind of you! And thank you for editing it so quickly! I'll report back if it is indeed the case.